# How can I set the Firebase Firestore rules if I want the user can access even there's no current user

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm using Firebase Firestore to collect user information in my current Android app. But I didn't quite get the Firestore rules. I write the rule like this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

But I want to user access the database even there's no current user because when the user sign up I'm checking the database if there's a current phone number in the database if not user can sign up this phone number. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Allow read/write access to all users under any conditions
// Warning: **NEVER** use this rule set in production; it allows
// anyone to overwrite your entire database.

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

> Not recommended: Read and write access to all users.

Have a look at [Fix insecure rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/insecure-rules) documentation from firebase for more details.